# How do I do a regex string replace with 1 variable?

Tags: c++, regex, vector

I'm working on something similar to a template engine for C++. Using the standard `<regex>` library, how do I find multiple matches in a string that has this pattern: `AB $1 BA` (not working with the escape char on AB, es. `\AB`, but working with any other char before AB) and store the matches in a string vector?

For example:

```
string main_string = "Something cool \AB blabla BA, something else AB first BA, something AB second BA more.";
vector<string> matches;
// algorithm here
```

and matches should contain `first` and `second`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string target_text(
        "Something cool \\AB blabla BA, something else AB first BA, "
        "something AB second BA more.");
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iter_type;
    std::regex rgx("[^\\\\]AB(.*?)BA");
    std::regex_iterator<iter_type> iter(target_text.begin(),
                                        target_text.end(),
                                        rgx);
    std::regex_iterator<iter_type> end;
    for ( ; iter != end; ++iter)
        result.push_back((*iter)[1].str());
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << result[i] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The regular expression isn't quite right; it won't match `"ABcBA"`, because it insists on one character (not a backslash) immediately before the rest of the pattern. That's fixable with a negative assert in place of the character group, but the simple test I tried didn't work and I don't want to put more time in it now.